# What is the time-complexity of the following code segment?

Tags: java, performance, time, runtime, big-o

For the code segment below estimate the time-complexity in the big-oh notation.

```
for (int i=0; i< n; i++)

for (int j=0; j*j <n;j++)

for (int k=0; k < n/2;k++)
    System.out.println (i+j+k);
```

I think that they are nested loops but I am not 100% sure. From what I can figure, the worst time for the first loop is O(n), the second is O(sqrt(n)), and the third is O(log n). Is that correct? And would I just multiply these values to get the time complexity for the whole loop?

Comment: it's O(n) * O(n^(1/2)) * O(n) = O(n^(5/2))

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon Krypton's comment, the loops are as follows:

- Loop 1: O(n), as you mentioned
- Loop 2: O(sqrt(n)) == O(n^(1/2)), as you mentioned.
- Loop 3: O(n/2), which, removing the constant factor, is O(n).

Multiplying, loops 1 and 3 together are O(n^2), and the three together are O(n^(5/2)) or O(n^(2.5)). This is in some odd grey area between quadratic and polynomial time.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i< n; i++)  ------------------------------------
                                                             |
    for (int j=0; j*j <n;j++) ----------------------         |
                                                   |         | O(n)
        for (int k=0; k < n/2;k++)  -------        |         |
                                          |O(n/2)  |O(n^1/2) |   
            System.out.println (i+j+k); ---        |         |
                                                   |         |
                              ----------------------         |        
                                                             |
                          ------------------------------------
```

Hence runtime

```
O(n)*O(n^1/2)*O(n/2) = O(n^(5/2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that O(n*(n^(1/2))*(n/2)). But I am not sure.

Comment: Add an explanation, rather than guessing the answer. One can get an answer on Google too.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i< n; i++) {               // O(n)
    for (int j=0; j*j <n;j++) {          // O(n^0.5)
        for (int k=0; k < n/2;k++) {     // O(0.5*n)
            System.out.println (i+j+k);  // O(1)
}}}
```

Same scope statements are added, nested statements are multiplied

`O((n)*(n^0.5)*(0.5*n)*(1))` = `O(0.5*(n^2)*(n^0.5))` = `O(0.5n^2.5)` = **`O(n^2.5)`**

Answer (score 0):

Loop 1 rate of change depends linearly on n -> O(n)  -- Linear

Loop 2 rate of change depends on the squared root of n -> O(n^0.5) -- Fractional power

Loop 3 rate of change depends linearly on n/2, but 1/2 constant can be removed -> O(n/2)  -- Linear

So, the overall complexity would be O(n) * O (n^0.5) * O (n) = O (n^2.5)

Check this for more information: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page72.html